private method accessible outside class
Why is there no compilation error in the code below? How is the private member accessible? What are the inner workings that make private class methods accessible without any reflection mechanism?
public class Outer {

    private static int data = 10;

    private static int LocalClass() {

        class Inner {

            public int data = 20;
            
            private int getData() {
                return data;
            }
        }

        Inner inner = new Inner();
        return inner.getData();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(data * LocalClass());
    }

}


The inner class must be in the same source file as the outer class.  The designers of Java therefore decided that in this case somewhat relaxed rules are reasonable.
